# How does KillSignal interact with TimeoutStopSec in systemd?

Tags: systemd

Can someone let me know the following about systemd service shutdown sequence

1. If I have specified `KillSignal=SIGTERM` then how does this interact this `TimeoutStopSec` ? Does this mean that during shutdown of service, first `SIGTERM` will be sent and if the service is still running after `TimeoutStopSec` `SIGKILL` will be sent (if `SendSIGKILL` is set to yes)? I am asking about the case where nothing is specified in `ExecStop`.
2. Does `TimeoutStopSec` take into account `ExecStop` and all `ExecPostStop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered in systemd mailing list. Cross-posting the answer here

> > Can someone let me know the following about systemd service shutdown
> >     sequence
> >
> > ```
> > 1.
> >
> > If I have specified KillSignal=SIGTERM then how does this interact this
> > TimeoutStopSec ? Does this mean that during shutdown of service, first
> > SIGTERM will be sent and if the service is still running after
> > TimeoutStopSec SIGKILL will be sent (if SendSIGKILL is set to yes? I am
> > asking about the case where nothing is specified in ExecStop.
> > ```
>
> Yes, that's correct
>
> > ```
> > 2.
> >
> > Does TimeoutStopSec take into account ExecStop and all ExecPostStop?
> > ```
>
> TimeoutStopSec is for every command. If ExecStopPost command fails (or
>   times out) subsequent commands are not executed, but if each command
>   requires almost TimeoutStopSec time, total execution time will be
>   close to ExecStopPost commands multiplied by TimeoutStopSec.